# how to attach pdf to mail in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.3.p1

what are the files needs to be changed to work mail with pdf attachment in magento 2.4 and above.
I go through lots of resources but nothing works for magento 2.4.

this is what i tried - [How to add pdf in mail in Magento 2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355666/how-to-add-pdf-in-mail-in-magento-2-4)

By this iam only getting template variables in mail. but pdf is not coming.

Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: HI @Lister pls refer this link. I added what i tried here. Pls look into this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355666/how-to-add-pdf-in-mail-in-magento-2-4

Comment: you can follow this https://meetanshi.com/blog/programmatically-attach-pdf-file-in-magento-2-email/

Comment: HI @ViralPatel It is not working for Magento 2.4